# Probability between multiple ranges

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If 3 events have a random chance of having a value of 20-35, what is the chance that their values will add up to 100?

If 4 events have the same chance, what is the chance their values *won't* add up to 100?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? You could, for instance, just count all the ways it could happen one way or another.

Comment: @Arthur I'm not sure how to set up the equation. I've never done any statistics like this before.

Comment: This is too vague a question. What is the probability distribution ? Is the r.v. discrete or continuous ?

Comment: And are the events independent? The question itself raises too many questions.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, assuming that the distribution is uniform, we can just  count in how many ways we can sum $100$: 
$$(30, 35, 35); (31 ,35, 34);( 32, 34,34);( 32, 33, 35);( 33 ,33, 34)$$
this because every number must be at least $30$. Considering the order, which here matters, we have $3+6+3+6+3=21$ possibilities. So the chances are
$$\frac{21}{16^3}.$$

For the second question it's not that simple, because counting all the cases it's a longer task.

Answer (score 0):

First you can transform random variables. You have $20\leq X_i \leq 35$. I assume that the four random variables are independent.

Now let $Y_i=X_i-20$. Therefore $0 \leq Y_i \leq 15$. The sum of the 4 random variables has to be $100-4\cdot 20=20$

The generating function is $\left(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{14}+x^{15} \right)^4$

You have to find the number of all $x^{20}$. This can be done by a using a calculator. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sum_%28k%3D0%29%5E15%20x%5Ek%29%5E4).

The result has to be divided by the number of all possible combinations: $16^4$

The final result is the converse probability.